# JButton used to begin animation not updating

Tags: java, swing, animation, applet, japplet

I have a problem in that when the program finishes drawing the GUI, I want to have a button which will collect information from the other Jobjects (JTextFields, Sliders etc.) and use it to dynamically construct a graph of the results of a `montecarlo` simulation. However the `repaint();` occurs only once the program exits the EventListener instead of after drawing the graph, and at each step of the animation. I believe it is a more general problem with the way the program is structured.

```
public class Runtime extends JApplet implements Runnable{
Border newSimulation;

    public void init() {
         this.setSize(800,600);
         try {
             SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     createGUI();
                 }
             });
         } catch (Exception e) { 
             System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
         }
     }
}

public class Graph extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    JPanel graph;

     public Graph(){
         super(new BorderLayout());
         super.setSize(800, 600);
         addParticleConstraints();
         addControlPanel();
         super.add(graph, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     }

     private JPanel addButton(JPanel control){
         JButton start = new JButton();
         start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
             {
                 beginSimulation();
                 graph.revalidate();//these do nothing
                 graph.repaint();
                 simulate();

             }
         });
     }

     private void beginSimulation(){
         gatherData();
         drawGraph();
         graph.revalidate(); //both of these do nothing
         graph.repaint();
     }

     private void simulate(){
         while(particles[noOfIsotopes] < noOfParticles){
             graph.revalidate(); //both do nothing
             graph.repaint();
             for(int i = 0; i < noOfParticles; i++){
                 montecarlo();
             }
                  addPoints();//adds points to graph by image.createGraphics() as graph 
                             //is stored as buffered image and modified
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the answer to "why" you're having problems. I would "guess" that you probably want to use a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule periodical changes to the state of your model and trigger new paint passes

Comment: Also, applets are deprecated and no longer supported - time to move on

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know it's historical, but such were the requirements for a project I was set.